# nth child cant select on laravel project

Tags: css, laravel, css-selectors

the same row has two of nth-child and cant select on working laravel project i don't have any idea please help me

```
.ps-deal-of-day:first-child(1)  .owl-item:first-child(1) {
    width: 25% !important;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid #ffb000;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```
<div class="ps-deal-of-day">
        <div class="owl-item">sadsa sadsad</div>
        <div class="owl-item">sadsa sadsad</div>
        <div class="owl-item">sadsa sadsad</div>
        <div class="owl-item">sadsa sadsad</div>

</div>
<div class="ps-deal-of-day">
        <div class="owl-item">sadsa sadsad</div>
        <div class="owl-item">sadsa sadsad</div>
        <div class="owl-item">sadsa sadsad</div>
        <div class="owl-item">sadsa sadsad</div>

</div>
<div class="ps-deal-of-day">
        <div class="owl-item"></div>
        <div class="owl-item"></div>
        <div class="owl-item"></div>
        <div class="owl-item"></div>

</div>
```

im tried on w3school code editor it works but in my laravel project it not works i put this css in footer
[image]

Comment: This is just an error in your syntax. Either use first-child or use nth-child(1). You should see an invalid value if you use your browser's dev tools inspect facility.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
.ps-deal-of-day:first-child .owl-item:first-child {
  width: 25% !important;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #ffb000;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```css
.ps-deal-of-day:first-child .owl-item:first-child {
    width: 25% !important;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid #ffb000;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ps-deal-of-day">
        <div class="owl-item">sadsa sadsad</div>
        <div class="owl-item">sadsa sadsad</div>
        <div class="owl-item">sadsa sadsad</div>
        <div class="owl-item">sadsa sadsad</div>

</div>
<div class="ps-deal-of-day">
        <div class="owl-item">sadsa sadsad</div>
        <div class="owl-item">sadsa sadsad</div>
        <div class="owl-item">sadsa sadsad</div>
        <div class="owl-item">sadsa sadsad</div>

</div>
<div class="ps-deal-of-day">
        <div class="owl-item"></div>
        <div class="owl-item"></div>
        <div class="owl-item"></div>
        <div class="owl-item"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: i know this works but i want to select first of ps-deal-of-day :/

Comment: @naveen Updated the above solution. Check now.

Comment: sorry bro still not working

Comment: It's working here in the demo. Can you please share a working link of your problem?

Comment: please view page source code ( Ctrl+U ) and try to find your Styles. Probably Its not loaded or pushed there. If it is there, Then some other styles may be overwriting them, so try to apply !important on each line. or share more information.